# GEB + jQuery: Contains throwing org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, geb

I am new to GEB and using jQuery.

I am trying to select or to find if a child of an element deeper n levels with specific text.

I am trying to use the contains selector but is not working as i was expecting.

Simple example:

```
...
<div class="widget-header-title">My Tasks</div>
...
```

I am trying to execute this selector

```
$('div:contains("My Tasks")')
```

but i am getting an exception:

```
Method threw 'org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException' exception.
```

What i really need to do is check if a child element of another contains text

```
<div id="taskLegend">
  <div>
      ....
      <text ....>Call</text>
      ....
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried this selector and i get the same exception above

```
$("#taskLegend").find("text:contains('Call')")
```

but using

```
$("#taskLegend").find("text")
```

it return all the elements "text" inside taskLegend

looks like is the contains that is not working.

Can someone spot what I am doing wrong?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Not that the first answer is wrong, but another way to do this is by passing a `By` object into you Jquery closure https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html

So for me personally I would probably use xpath (although note xpath is technically the slowest)

so it would look something like this:

```
$(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'My Tasks')]"))
```

This will return all divs that contain text 'My Tasks'

Answer (score 1):

the quotations are for the element and its tags (ex. "h1.class")

if you wish to search using text:contains it needs to be in this format:

```
$("#taskLegend").find("text", text:contains("Call"))
```

the word "text" in your case has 2 meanings; a text element itself and the text of an element